# MVVM Pattern and access from ViewModel to Model

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm

As I understand MVVM, the XViewModel of class ModelX should hide this class from access of all other classes, so that XViewModel notice every changes that is make to the model. But there is a problem, I can't solve.

Imagine I have some classes as:
ProjectModel, UserModel and GroupModel. 
ProjectModel contains a list of UserModel and a list GroupModel with is a list of UserModel.

For all these classes there exists ViewModels:
ProjectViewModel, UserViewModel, GroupViewModel. ProjectViewModel wraps all list of models into a ObservableCollection, if changes are needed, otherwise in a ReadOnlyCollection. In my case its a ObservableCollection.

Now imagine, I would like to add a group to a project. So I call something like

```
UserViewModel user1 = new UserViewModel("Chriss");
UserViewModel user2 = new UserViewModel("Jena");
ProjectViewModel project = new ProjectViewModel();
project.Groups.Add(new GroupViewModel(user1, user2));
```

Now the constructor of GroupViewModel has to creates its field _groupModel by calling the constructor of GroupModel:

```
public GroupModel(UserModel user1, UserModel user2){}
```

But unfortunately, GroupViewModel has no access to the field _user of UserViewModel and so it can't create its own field _groupModel.

I was confronted with this problem more then one time, but nether on Google nor here I can't find a good solution for this.

Possibilie solutions I thought about:

1. Give access to model by holding a property for that in every ViewModel class. But this conflicts with the idea of hiding the model from unauthorized access.
2. Implement a "public static GroupModel CreateGroup()" in UserViewModel, because this has access to its model. But this sounds a bit dirty.

How did you solve this problem? Does I miss something on MVVP-pattern?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var user1 = new User("Chriss");
var user2 = new User("Jena");
var userModel1 = new UserViewModel(user1);
var userModel2 = new UserViewModel(user2);
var group = new Group(userModel1 , userModel2);
var project = new ProjectViewModel();
project.Groups.Add(new GroupViewModel(group));
```

So you are creating the group externally and pass that to the GroupViewModel. The creation of the Model shouldn't be ViewModel's responsability.

Hope it helps.

*EDIT:* Fixed the creation of the User instance.

Comment: In this example you are passing UserViewModels to Group which I assume is a model.  This seems off to me.

Comment: I thought about this and in my case this will solve the problem, but not in general. Its is not guarantied, that I have always access to the model. Maybe the model is part of an external library and I have to wrap it into a VM in order to get DataBinding working. In that case, my GroupModel has not constructor (UserViewModel, UserViewModel), only (UserModel, UserModel)